# Android Studio OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I have made an app and have been testing it on Android Studio with different screen sizes (AVDs). I started with small one and worked my way up. It is very slow, but I got up to 5.96" screens and everything worked fine. When trying it with the 5.96" I got the following error:

```
01-01 11:59:09.226    1317-1317/com.luanca.charangomaster E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 29833456 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 12MB until OOM"
01-01 11:59:09.228    1317-1317/com.luanca.charangomaster D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
01-01 11:59:09.232    1317-1317/com.luanca.charangomaster D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
01-01 11:59:09.246    1317-1317/com.luanca.charangomaster E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.luanca.charangomaster, PID: 1317
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:490)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.CustomDialog.<init>(CustomDialog.java:25)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.ChordActivity$2.onClick(ChordActivity.java:178)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:490)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.CustomDialog.<init>(CustomDialog.java:25)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.ChordActivity$2.onClick(ChordActivity.java:178)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 29833456 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:490)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.CustomDialog.<init>(CustomDialog.java:25)
            at com.luanca.charangomaster.ChordActivity$2.onClick(ChordActivity.java:178)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Now I'm confused, because the app worked with all other screen sizes. Anyone with some insight in how to fix this? Is it a code error or is it something I have to fix in Android Studio?

Works fine with 7" and 10" screens too. I don't understand the error with 5.96"...

This is where it happens. When I press one of the first 2 buttons (which should open a dialog while still on the same activity (as links because I reach limit of stackoverflow):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43384650/activity_main.xml

And the 2 dialogs:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43384650/dialog.xml

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43384650/dialog2.xml

Comment: It is really hard to tell what are you trying to do that might cause this problem. Is it working with bitmaps or video or just views?

Comment: It is views with buttons (some of them have textures as backgrounds). But how would that explain that it only fails with one screensize?

Comment: Is everythinh 100% identical across all emuulators you tried? It could be some mathematical stuff related to the number 5.96" ...e.g. trying to calculate width or hight of ui elements with division and multiplication of hard coded numbers??? I don't know more really

Comment: And you better check where exactly the code generates this error and paste some code here.

Comment: Do you scale your bitmap regarding screen size/density, before you set it to ImageView?

Comment: ur image is bigger than the device size....pls post xml code to tell which image..

Comment: Test in Device rather then in emulator.

Comment: when this error is coming?

Comment: When I click on one of the buttons that opens a dialog. I'll just post all 3

Comment: is there any images in ur dialog xml layout?

Comment: added the xml. They have an image as background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the drawable wood

i hope its an image and just
replace some color code to this line n try

```
android:background="@drawable/wood"
```

as

```
android:background="#000000"
```

i hope its work for u.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and fixed it by increasing the VM Heap Size of the AVD from 64 MB to 128 MB.